# Dvoretzky–Kiefer–Wolfowitz inequality holds for discrete distributions?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions, sampling

I am wondering whether [Dvoretzky–Kiefer–Wolfowitz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%E2%80%93Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_inequality) holds for discrete distributions? Any comments or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your attempt to deal with the problem? You searched examples or counterexamples?

Comment: I am working on a research problem in which the empirical cumulative distribution function is discrete. I would like to find some bounds on this empirical distribution function so was wondering whether I can use DKW.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Dvoretzky–Kiefer–Wolfowitz (DKW) inequality holds unchanged for discrete distributions.

See, for example, Comment 2(iii) of [Massart (1990)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2244426): "inequalities (1.4) and (1.5) remain valid when F is not continuous." In particular, Inequality (1.5) is the two-sided DKW inequality.